# Spring ConstraintValidator customizing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-validator

*Before asking questions, I apologize for not being good at English.*

I'm implementing a custom `ConstraintValidator` for cross-field validation as shown below.

#### Validation Target Class

```java
public class ValidationTarget {
    @Valid
    private Inner inner;

    @ValidDates(fromField = "from", toField = "to",
                message = "{from} must not be later than {to}")
    public class Inner {
        private Date from;
        private Date to;
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### CustomConstraintValidator

```java
// imports ...

public class CustomConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidDates, Object> {

    private String fromFieldName;
    private String toFieldName;
    private String message;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidDatesvalidationSpec) {
        this.fromFieldName = validationSpec.fromField();
        this.toFieldName = validationSpec.toField();
        this.message = validationSpec.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object target, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        Date startDateObject = getFieldValue(target, fromFieldName);
        Date endDateObject = getFieldValue(target, toFieldName);

        if (start.after(end)) {
            addConstraintViolation(toFieldName, message, ctx);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void addConstraintViolation(String propertyName, String message, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        ctx.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message)
           .addPropertyNode(propertyName)
           .addConstraintViolation()
           .disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
    }

    private Date getFieldValue(Object instance, String fieldName) {
        Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(instance.getClass(), fieldName);
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
        return (Date) ReflectionUtils.getField(field, instance);
    }
```

}

In the above code, `Inner` class object is returned when calling `getInvalidValue()` of `ConstraintViolation`.

I want to change this value only to a specific field value rather than to the entire `Inner` class.

Comment: Since you are having a validation on more than one field, you can only create a class level annotation validation and not field level.